# How create global ajax success handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have ajax request:

```
$.post(url, function (result) { //some code })
```

End I need the global ajaxSuccess

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr, settings) {
            var redirectTo = xhr.getResponseHeader('RedirectTo');
            if (redirectTo) {
                window.location = redirectTo;
                xhr.abort();
            }
        });
```

Now the first call is `post`. second `ajaxSuccess`.

I need what ajaxSuccess call first

actual:
    /*
    console result

```
ajaxSend
post
ajaxSuccess
*/
```

expected:
    /*
    console result

```
ajaxSend
ajaxSuccess
post
*/
```

Comment: No idea what you are asking.

Comment: xhr is the ajax object that was called first.

Comment: Are you saying you need to know if it was post or get?

Comment: no, I need handler any request by ajax in global function

Comment: And you want the post success being called after the global ajaxSuccess?

Comment: I'm still completely lost on what you are trying to do. I'd suggest rethinking your question and giving us a lot more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something method of opposite of ajaxSuccess() method. It is [ajaxSend() method](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/).

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, xhr, settings) {
  console.log("ajaxSend");
});

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr, settings) {
  console.log("ajaxSuccess");
});

$.post(url, function (result) {
  console.log("post");
});


/*
console result

ajaxSend
post
ajaxSuccess
*/
```

**Added :** You can do like this, but I'm not suggest the follow code. Just pick the idea.

```
(function ($) {
        $.post = function (url, data, callback, type) {
            // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
            if (jQuery.isFunction(data)) {
                type = type || callback;
                callback = data;
                data = undefined;
            }

            return jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: type,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (success, statusText, jqXHR) {
                        jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxCallbackBefore", [jqXHR, success]);
                        callback(success, statusText, jqXHR);
                    }
                });
        };
    })(jQuery);

jQuery.fn.ajaxCallbackBefore = function (fn) {
    return this.on("ajaxCallbackBefore", fn);
};

$(function () {
        $(document).ajaxCallbackBefore(function () {
                console.log("ajaxCallbackBefore");
            });
        $(document).ajaxSend(function () {
                console.log("ajaxSend");
            });
        $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
                console.log("ajaxSuccess");
            });

        $.post(url, function (result) {
                console.log("post");
            });
    });
```

Comment: I have had: 1.ajaxSend 2. post 3.ajaxSuccess.
But I need 1.ajaxSend 2. ajaxSuccess 3.post

Comment: @simplydenis Please check new code. But I think you need to find other solution.